# Trouble calling the Unix command kill(int PID) through c program

Tags: c, unix, kill, pid

I am writing a program in C in one of my systems classes. We write c code and run it in a unix environment. I have looked all over the internet, but can't seem to find any way to make the kill(int PID) command work. The code will compile and run fine, but if I use the

```
ps -u username
```

command in a unix command prompt (after execution has completed of course,) it says that the all of the processes I tried to kill in my c code are still running. I can kill them from the unix command prompt by manually entering their PIDs, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do it inside of my program.

In this particular program, I am trying to kill process CC, which is a process that just infinitely calls usleep(100); until terminated.

I tried using kill(C3, -9); and variations of execlp("kill", "kill", C3, (char *)0); but still no luck. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? My only guess is that the kill command is being passed the wrong PID parameter, but if that's the case, I have no idea how I would get the correct one.

EDIT: Also, the kill command returns a value of zero, which I believe means that it "succeeded" in executing the command.

EDIT: Just noticed that the solution to my problem was in the instructions for the assignment all along. Yup. I'm stupid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
        //
        //Step 7
        //
        //Create process C3
        int C3=fork();
        if (C3==0)
        {
                execlp("CC", "CC", (char *)0);
        }
        else
        {
        usleep(500000);
        //
        //Step 8
        //
        int ps=fork();
        if (ps==0)
        {
                execlp("ps", "ps", "-u", "cooley", (char *)0);
        }
        else
        {
                wait(NULL);
                kill(C3);
        }
        }
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Running gcc with all warnings on `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  would have pointed you to this issue already during the compilation phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the [`kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) system call with only one argument, when it takes two. This leads to undefined behavior since then the second argument can by anything. You should get a warning about this when compiling.

The second argument should be a value from `<signal.h>` (see the [`signal(7)` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal)).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The solution to the problem was just adding ", SIGKILL" after the PID#.